# Swiper with video or image on the card

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-swiper

I have a list of objects that contain a **video** or **photo**

I would like to make scrolling possible (up - down - up, something like in TikTok). Each card has a full-screen image or video.

For this I used the library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swiper

Scrolling works as intended, but there are other problems:

- all objects load immediately (there should be some pagination)
- all objects start immediately (when the video has sound then everyone starts playing)

Is there another useful solution or can something be done with this library?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `onIndexChanged={(index) => this.setState({index})}` to set and get the `index`

And then set Video disable auto play.

If `this.state.index` equal that page, then that video plays start or it pause?